# How to write a specification to eagerly fetch a lazy ManyToMany relation?

Tags: spring-data-jpa

This may have been asked before but I don't seem to get it.

I have a little complexer ManyToMany relation between users and roles. The linking table has some more attributes, so it ended being an Entity itself.

The mapping is defined as lazy, because, most of the time, I don't want to fetch the roles together with the user(s). But, of course, there is a use case when I rather fetch the roles together with the users in a single query.

`User` class:

```
@Entity
public class User {

  [...]  // other attributes

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private Set<User2Role> userToRoles = new HashSet<>();

  [...] // getters and setters
}
```

Link entity:

```
@Entity
public class User2Role {

  @ManyToOne
  private User user;

  @ManyToOne
  private Role role;

  [...] // getters, setters and other attributes
}
```

And there is of course also a `Role` class (contents not relevant).

What I have so far:

```
Specification<User> specification = Specification.where(null);
specification.and((user, query, cb) -> {
  if (Long.class != query.getResultType()) {
    user.fetch(User_.userToRoles, JoinType.LEFT).fetch(User2Role_.role, JoinType.LEFT);
  }
  return null;
});

[...]  // other conditions
```

What did I miss ?
Note that I do not want to filter on any attributes of `Role`, just on `User` attributes, but want to display (in UI) the roles together with the user.

Answer (score 0):

I just needed a short break to clear my mind and figure out the foolish mistake I made and was not seeing :)

But to spare someone a few hours of their life looking at such things, `Specification.and()` **does not change** the Specification object, it returns a new one.

So, the correct code is:

```
Specification<User> specification = Specification.where(null);
specification = specification.and((user, query, cb) -> {
  if (Long.class != query.getResultType()) {
    user.fetch(User_.userToRoles, JoinType.LEFT).fetch(User2Role_.role, JoinType.LEFT);
  }
  return null;
});
```